# How to retrieve information from $.post

Tags: php, javascript, json, html

I am currently running JavaScript after a click of a button in my PHP page which saves data.

`a.js`:

```
function save(){

var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

var newItem = {};
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

newItem[num] = {
    "methv": document.getElementById("methv").value
    ,'q1': document.getElementById("q1").value,
    'q2':document.getElementById("q2").value,
    'q3':document.getElementById("q3").value,
    'q4':document.getElementById("q4").value,
    'comm':document.getElementById("comm").value
};

oldItems.push(newItem);

localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));

$.post('edit.php', { items: JSON.stringify(oldItems) }, function(response) {

});
```

In the PHP page, my form looks like this:

edit.php

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <select name="methv" class="textfields" id="methv" style="width:110px" > 
    <option value= "dont know">dont know </option>

<select name="q1" class="textfields" id="q1" style="width:50px" > 
<option value= "-">-</option>
<option value= "L">L</option>

<select name="q2" class="textfields" id="q2" style="width:50px" > 
<option value= "-">-</option>
<option value= "L">L</option>

<select name="q3" class="textfields" id="q3" style="width:50px" > 
<option value= "-">-</option>
<option value= "L">L</option>

<select name="q4" class="textfields" id="q4" style="width:50px" > 
<option value= "-">-</option>
<option value= "L">L</option>

<textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="comm" name="comm" style="width:300px"><?php echo $post['addcomment'] ;?></textarea> 

</form>
```

When I run the PHP page and click the button, in the console, I get a post:

```
[{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}},{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}}]
```

These are the results from the local storage- one from before and one after it- being clicked (adds every time the button is clicked). How do I get this information and display it on the PHP page?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: where do i delcare this in the php file or js file?

Comment: did you look at the domain? this function converts json string to php object or array

Comment: Sorry im quite new to this but i know what the function does but i am unsure where to decode this as i have tried before and i get an undefined error

Comment: To add it to the page use jquery `.html()` or `.append()` or some other function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have an edit.php file to handle the POST request? This link might help you if not. http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/12/how-to-handle-json-post-request-using-php/

Once edit.php is set up to handle the request and return data, you'll probably want to manipulate that data within your response function.

```
$.post('edit.php', { items: JSON.stringify(oldItems) }, function(data) {
    // Do something here, for example...
    alert(data);
});
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey David, Thanks for replying. The problem i have is i need this data to appear in PHP so i can connect it to the database and update the database.I cant use PHP functions in the response can i?

Comment: Any time. Is `edit.php` the file that displays the form, or the file that's supposed to process the form? Whatever file you put in your `$.post()` function should be the one that's set up like the link I linked you above, you may need to create a `form-process.php` or something, that does all that. The response allows you to access whatever data is returned when you call the file you specified in the jQuery `$.post()` function